# How can I create floating objects animation

Tags: animation, adobe-after-effects, cinema4d

How can I make these kind of animation?
Like in this project by Pentagram studio. https://www.pentagram.com/work/unesco-futures-literacy-summit
Or this https://bangbangeducation.ru/

Is it AE, Cinema 4D, or somth else?
Thanks!

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Generally, there's no way to tell what software was used just by looking at a video. It could be any of those you mentioned. Also note that video editing is off-topic here anyway. Sorry about that.

Comment: In the 1st example the moving parts are silhouettes of 3D shapes which bounce inside rectangular room. It can be made with hard work in an advanced video editor like After Effects or with 3D kinematics simulation in a 3D physics capable program. The 3D simulation needs harder work to get started, in After Effects you must define every motion path and rotation separately from the start to the end. How a beginner starts from scratch and creates a working copy is far too wide to be answered here.

Comment: @user287001 Thanks for suggestions!

Comment: @BillyKerr thank you for reply anyway!)

Comment: @GeraVolobuev - also note that video editing questions are better suited to [Video Production Stack Exchange](https://video.stackexchange.com/). If you're interested in 3D modelling and animation, Blender is one option. There's aslo a [Blender Stack Exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/)